# Views PHP is outputting incorrectly

Tags: views

I'm trying to work with [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) but for some reason something is going completely wrong. I have a content field called telephone. In this field is a number "06-12345678" now I want to use Views PHP to remove the "-" so I get the number "0612345678".

What I do is I make a view with the field Telephone and a Global: PHP field underneath it. In this Global: PHP field I add the following code to see if it is working.

```
<?php print $row->field_telephone; ?>
```

So when I save this field I get the output: "11" instead of 06-12345678.

When I try `<?php print $row->field_title; ?>` it does give me the suspected output..? What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: Install Devel module and the code `kpr($row)` will give you the exact structure of `$row` object. then print the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data->field_field_telephone[0]['raw']['value'];
```

This will give you your value from that field in `Views PHP`. If you use dpm() from Devel module it will show you that `$row->field_telephone` is 11. that's the NID.

Try to avoid using Views PHP unless you are doing something too complex for views. And even then you should try to write a custom module to interact with views instead of saving code in the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Could you please explain why I should avoid Views PHP is it unsafe?